# Count of same records from two columns using if condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `question_attempts`. This table having two columns `rightanswers` and `youranswer`.

I want to get the count of records `rightanswer`=`youranswer`.  This is my entire code actually.

```
$quizsections = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz_sections");
while($quizsectionsrslt = mysql_fetch_array($quizsections)){
$quizsectionsid        = $quizsectionsrslt['id'];
$quizsectionsheading   = $quizsectionsrslt['heading'];
$quizsectionsquizid    = $quizsectionsrslt['quizid'];
$quizsectionsfirstslot = $quizsectionsrslt['firstslot'];
echo $quizsectionsheading."<br />";
$quizslots = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz_slots WHERE `quizid`=$quizsectionsquizid LIMIT ".($quizsectionsfirstslot-1).", 10");
while($quizslotsrslt = mysql_fetch_array($quizslots)){
    $quizslotids = $quizslotsrslt['questionid'];
    $questions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question_attempts WHERE `questionid`=$quizslotids");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($quizslots);
    while($answercount = mysql_fetch_array($questions)){
        $answercountrslt = $answercount['questionid'];
        echo $rightanswer = $answercount['rightanswer'];
        echo $youranser = $answercount['responsesummary']."<br />";
//Here want to display the count of rightanswer and count of wrong answer.
    }
    }
    echo "Total Questions : ".$num_rows."<br /><br />";
}
```

Comment: Got the result as on my requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Below:

```
$rightanswercount=0;
$badanswercount=0;

    $questions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question_attempts");
        while($answercount = mysql_fetch_array($questions)){
    $rightanswer = $answercount['rightanswer'];
    $youranser = $answercount['youranswer'];
    if($youranser == $rightanswer)
            {
                $rightanswercount=$rightanswercount+1;
            }
            else
            {
               $badanswercount=$badanswercount+1;
            }
        }

echo "Right Count=".$rightanswercount;
echo "Bad Count=".$badanswercount;
```

Comment: Amrut! It's working awesome. But, the result repeating many times after placing this code. I just updated my questions. look into it plz.

Comment: Hurrey! Got the result what i want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get only count then u can use mysql_num_rows

```
$questions = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM question_attempts where rightanswers=youranswer");
$count=mysql_num_rows($questions);
```

Comment: i tried with this too. Have a look into my code once. i used $num_rows instead of $count

Answer (score 1):

You can do your task by sql query, and perform stuff on correct answers

```
$questions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question_attempts where rightanswers=youranswer");

$count = mysql_num_rows($questions);

// $count is number of right answers
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($questions))
{
    // Stuff on right answers
}
```

Comment: Vipul, i already tried with this, You may understand if you look into my code once.